# PostgreSQL determine column type when data_type is set to ARRAY

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I came across an oddity where PostgreSQL sets the `data_type` to `ARRAY` in the `information_schema.columns` table. I did the following query to gain some insight:

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.columns 
WHERE table_schema NOT IN ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema') 
AND table_name='__table_name__';
```

I noticed the `udt_name` column and am wondering if it is a reliable way to determine what *type* of array the column's data is?

```
SELECT column_name, data_type, udt_name FROM information_schema.columns 
WHERE table_schema NOT IN ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema') 
AND table_name='__table_name__';
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One option is to simply cast `udt_name` to a `regtype`:

```
SELECT column_name, data_type, udt_name::regtype
FROM information_schema.columns 
WHERE table_schema = 'public'
  AND table_name='table_name';
```

Another option is to use the function `format_type()`, but that needs the `oid` of the data type:

```
select c.attname, pg_catalog.format_type(c.atttypid, NULL) as data_type
from pg_attribute c
  join pg_class t on c.attrelid = t.oid
  join pg_namespace n on t.relnamespace = n.oid
where t.relname = 'table_name'  -- your table name
  and n.nspname = 'public' -- table schema
  and c.attnum >= 0 -- exclude internal columns
```